# Letter Bar while scrolling by indexes UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, indexing, sections

I have something like this 
http://www.allappsdevelopers.com/images/TopicImages/TableView%20in%20iphone/index.png

And i also want to show something like MBProgressHud while scrolling by these letters. I saw in some apps that when u scrolling by indexes, the letter is showing in black rounded view at the center of the window.

Note: not when scrolling manually, but only when scrolling by using indexes.

Can i somehow detect start dragging on this panel and end dragging? Or is there any other way to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made my own solution:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) MBProgressHUD *letterBar;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSTimer *letterBarTimer;
```

---

```
self.letterBar = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
[self.letterBar setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[self.letterBar setMode:MBProgressHUDModeText];
[self.view addSubview:self.letterBar];
```

---

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    [self.letterBarTimer invalidate];
    [self.letterBar setLabelText:title];
    [self.letterBar show:YES];
    self.letterBarTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(hideLetterBar) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    return index;
}

-(void)hideLetterBar {
    [self.letterBar hide:YES];
}
```